# Error on focus on the Edit Text in the Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView.
Each row in the recycler view has an edit text component.

The app crashed when the keyboard is **not** visible, and user clicks on any of the EditText components **in the area that will be occupied by the keyboard once it pops-up**.
In other words, EditText boxes in the upper half of the screen doesn't throw the exception.

**This error is specific to devices with Android 6.0 or more.**

For devices with lower version than **Android 6.0** , the app works perfectly well as the EditText get automatically scrolled above the keypad.

Following is the exception.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: in.haplotech.aims, PID: 12723
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
     at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:5502)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:5431)
     at android.widget.ScrollView.isWithinDeltaOfScreen(ScrollView.java:1167)
     at android.widget.ScrollView.onSizeChanged(ScrollView.java:1576)
     at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:17641)
     at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:17603)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5618)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5618)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5618)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5618)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5618)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5618)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5618)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2374)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2101)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1278)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6357)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Following is my Adapter code:

```
public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<User> dataList;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

public StudentAdapter(List<User> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.mImageLoader = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(AppName.getInstance().getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
}

public List<User> getDataList() {
    return dataList;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_exam_student, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final User std = dataList.get(position);

    RelativeLayout studentHolder = viewHolder.studentHolder;
    NetworkImageView imgStudentPic = viewHolder.imgStudentPic;
    final TextView tvName = viewHolder.tvName;
    final EditText etMarks = viewHolder.etMarks;

    tvName.setText(std.toString());
    etMarks.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {//VVIMP : used to maintain the state of scrolled items.
    //Resource : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065267/recyclerview-changing-items-during-scroll
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public RelativeLayout studentHolder;
    public NetworkImageView imgStudentPic;
    public TextView tvName;
    public EditText etMarks;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        studentHolder = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentHolder);
        imgStudentPic = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgStudentPic);
        tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        etMarks = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.etMarks);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: add your adapter code as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7100555/5212133)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing/catching "IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100555/preventing-catching-illegalargumentexception-parameter-must-be-a-descendant-of)

Comment: Can you please describe the problem clearly and with code as well?

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar, The question marked by you, did not solve my problem.

Comment: Please note, I am using a **Recycler View** with an **Edit Text** component in each of the rows.  The exception is thrown only after I do some scrolling on the recycler view and then click on any of the edit text boxes.

Comment: @Sanket I have tried with edit text in recycler view and it is scrolling perfectly. Even though I tried with "addTextChangedListener" it is not crasing. Do one thing comment complex part of code and try is it crashing because of editText.

Comment: @suprita, the error is thrown only on devices with **Android 6.0 or more**.  Also, the complex logic has been removed, still the problem persists.

Comment: I have updated the question with few more insights. It seems the actual problem is with keypad.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Here is code for adapter I am successfully able to scroll with recycler view containing edit text in each row.
 public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<Movie> movieList;

@Override
public MovieHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MovieHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = movieList.get(position);

    holder.ed.setText(movie.getTitle());
}
public MovieAdapter(List<Movie> movieList)
{

    this.movieList = movieList;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movieList.size();
}



class MovieHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    public EditText ed;
    public MovieHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);

        ed = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
}}
```

MainActivity Class Code:

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(movieList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

If you are still getting problem please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Problem still persists. I have updated the question, please have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to the activity tag in the android manifest file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This is just a temporary solution, as there are few UX issues.

The actual issue can be studied in this question : [Recyclerview not scrolling to end when keyboard opens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102741/recyclerview-not-scrolling-to-end-when-keyboard-opens)